# How i can show some textfield when click button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want make a code, when i entry the number and then click submit, it will be show some textfield as many numbers as input.

this is example of code :

```
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="2">

<p>Click the button to get some textfield.</p>

<button">submit</button>
```

and when i click submit button (example : input number=2) this will be show two textfield like a code :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1" name="text1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2" name="text2">
```

Comment: You might need to look at jquery to achieve that

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried and problems that you encountered.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple example.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);

  var html = "";
  for (var counter = 0; counter < number; counter++) {
    html += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="text' + counter + '" name="text1' + counter + '">'
  }
  document.getElementById("allNewTextBoxes").innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="2">\
<p>Click the button to get some textfield.</p>
<button>submit</button>
<p id="allNewTextBoxes"></p>
```

Comment: @LukmanAzhari Hard to know unless you can share a specific problem about your implementation in your **next question**.

Answer (score 0):

Put your two text field inside a div

```
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="2">
<p>Click the button to get some textfield.</p>
<button>submit</button>

<div id="show" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1" name="text1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2" name="text2">
</div>
```

and then use toggle method to show text field

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#show").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<label>Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="number">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="click me!">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$value=$_POST['number'];
for ($i=1; $i < $value; $i++) {
echo "<br>";
echo "<label>label".$i."</label>";
echo "<input type='text' name=text".$i." id=text".$i." class='form-control'>";
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```